# A power function does't return a float

Tags: c

I've made a program to find a power of any number. It sort of works but my problem is that it doesn't return float as it should

```
float power(float num, int pwr)
{
    float idx;
    float val;

    val = 1;
    idx = 0.00;

    while (idx < pwr)
    {
        val *= num;
        idx++;
        printf("%f\n", val); 
    }

    return val;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%2.f\n", power(1.03, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

The result I get is this ;

```
$ gcc power.c && ./a.out
1.030000
1.060900
1.092727
1.125509
1.159274
 1
```

Comment: printf("%f\n",power(1.03,5));

Comment: What's `si`?  Please provide the actual code you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is returning a `float` and a `float` is being printed.  The format specifier `%2.f` is telling it to not print any digits after the decimal point.

You may have instead wanted `%.2f` which will print 2 decimal places.